# Node.js not showing page properly

Tags: node.js

I watched a Youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SB-oPvvd6F4&ab_channel=ModernWeb) & copied the code from it but my page is not loading properly, It looks like this-
[image]

Node.js code -

```
import express from "express";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

//init server 
const app = express();

//middlewares
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json())//enables from sharing
//routes
//home route 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html", {root : "public"})
})
// 404 route 
app.get('/404', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("404.html", {root : "public"})
})
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/404')
})
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
})
```

Comment: It looks like you have some `file://` paths in your HTML files. You cannot load `file:` URLs from `http:` pages. Make sure to use page-relative or root-relative paths instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `file:` path inside of your HTML code (or other public files) which isn't possible as you aren't reading from a filesystem, you are using HTTP. Use proper paths instead in your links.